# Search Refinement for Choice Field

Tags: search, sharepoint-enterprise, refinement-panel

I have added a choice field to my content type.  I have added a mapped field in search administration for this new field.
The field is being returned when searching for a document (based on xsl) all results output.

I am trying to add a refinement for this choice field and it is not displaying in the list of available refinements.  I have modified the Filter Category Definition to include this new field as shown below.

```
<Category Title="Service Team"
  Description="Use this filter to restrict results by type of document"
  Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"
  MetadataThreshold="5" NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="6"
  MaxNumberOfFilters="20" SortBy="Frequency"
  SortByForMoreFilters="Name" SortDirection="Descending"
  SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending" ShowMoreLink="True"
  MappedProperty="serviceteam" MoreLinkText="show more"
  LessLinkText="show fewer" />
```

I have also increased the 'number of categories to display' to 10 from 6 but still the refinement option for field serviceteam is not visible.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is your SharePoint 2010 an upgrade from SharePoint 2007?

I had a issues once with a managed property that was mapped to a choice field. Turned out that there is an issue with this when your SharePoint 2010 is an upgrade from 2007. We changed the field from choice to a managed metadata field.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run a full crawl after creating the managed property.

Comment: A full crawl was run, the mapped property shows up in the search results, but when i create the refinement i am unable to refine based on the property.